# "At the corner of the house" vs "In the corner of the house"

Tags: prepositions

I recently learned that we use "**in** the corner" when referring to an enclosure. So saying "there is a chair in the corner of the room" *(where "room" is an enclosure)* is correct. However, I recently came across an example where the preposition "at" was used with "house":

> There is a chair at the corner of the house.

Why is *at* used here even though "house" is an enclosure? Why not use "in" here?

Comment: Perhaps the chair is "at" an ***outside*** corner of the house. If not, using ***at*** is very unlikely (but it's not inherently "syntactically invalid", just "not common"). But you can certainly say *Walk up to the main road and stand **at** the corner* (where that's an "outside" context).

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers here, if the corner is outside the house it would be "at" but if you're referring to something inside the house you will use "in"

Comment: Party at my house - Does this mean that the party is happening outside and not inside the house?